# Динамическое создание фрагментов

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня появилась задача такого плана:
Нужно создавать фрагменты в соответствие с количеством элементов, пришедших с сервера. Скажем, я получил 20 элементов и на каждый из них мне нужен фрагмент. Переключаться между ними буду по кнопке после того, как просмотрю текущий.

Ответ такой:

```
{
  "0": {
         "id":"1",
         "title":"title",
       },

  "1": {
          "id":"2",
          "id":"title2"
       }
}
```

Элемент - объект с пометкой "0", "1" и т.д.

Нужно ли приходящий список элементов предварительно сохранять в БД и из него вытаскивать последовательно каждый из них?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужно ли приходящий список элементов предварительно сохранять в БД и
>   из него вытаскивать последовательно каждый из них?

Это зависит от задачи. Для офлайна можно закэшировать данные где-нибудь.

> Скажем, я получил 20 элементов и на каждый из них мне нужен фрагмент.
>   Переключаться между ними буду по кнопке после того, как просмотрю
>   текущий.

Такая конструкция сложна и скорее всего даже будет тормозить работу UI.

Гораздо проще и эффективнее создать 1 типовой фрагмент и по кнопке отображать в нём тот или иной элемент. Но, такой поход оправдан, если все элементы одинаковые или имеют не очень сильные различия.

Comment: Данные все одинаковые будут. Получается, мне нужно сделать абстрактный класс для фрагментов?

Comment: Вам не нужно создавать много фрагментов. Вам нужен один фрагмент с методом наподобие `setItem`, в который по кнопке Вы будете передавать объект для отображения. Разумеется при изменении модели в сеттере обновляете UI.